# failed to compile unexpected token 57:1 Return(

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a stubornly persistent syntax error that i cant solve for over an hour ,  it sais failed to compile unexpected token 57:1 Return(

im still a noob in react so sorry if im asking a stupid question , but i cant seem to figure out the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated thanks!!!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Car from './car';
import { CarsRef, timeRef } from '../admin/reference';

import { Table, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';

import Icon from 'react-icons-kit';
import { bin } from 'react-icons-kit/icomoon';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';



class CarsList extends Component {



  state = {

    Cars: [],
   Carsloading: true

  };


 componentWillMount() { 

CarsRef.on('value', snap => {
      const tasks = [];
      let Cars = []
      snap.forEach(shot => {
       Cars.push({ ...shot.val(), key: shot.key });
      });
      console.log(Cars);
      this.setState({ Cars: Cars, CarsLoading: false });
    });
  }




 render(){  
  const { Cars, CarsLoading } = this.state;
    const orderedcars = Cars;

    let carList;
  if (CarsLoading) {
        carList = <div className="TaskList-empty">Loading...</div>; 
    } 


     else if (Cars.length) {
        carList = (
            <ul className="TaskList">
              {Cars.map(car => (       
 return (
    <div>
      <Row>
        <Col md="12">
          <div className="card border-secondary mb-3">
            <div className="card-header text-success">
              <h4>
                <Link to={`/cars/${car.id}`}>
                  {car.year} {car.make} {car.model} {car.trim}
                </Link>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
              <Row>
                <Col md="5">
                  <CardImg className="carlist-margin" top width="100%" src={car.link} alt={car.make} />
                </Col>
                <Col md="4">
                  <Table className="striped">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Engine:</td>
                      <td>{car.engine}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Drive Type:</td>
                      <td>{car.drive_type}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Body:</td>
                      <td>{car.body_type}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Exterior Color:</td>
                      <td>{car.ext_color}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Interior Color:</td>
                      <td>{car.int_color}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Transmission:</td>
                      <td>{car.transmission}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>VIN:</td>
                      <td>{car.vin}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  </Table>
                </Col>
                <Col md="3">
                  <Table className="striped">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td className="text-primary text-right">
                          <strong>
                            MSRP:
                          </strong>
                          </td>
                        <td className="text-primary text-right">
                          <strong>
                            ${car.price}
                          </strong>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td className="text-danger text-right">Dealer Discount:</td>
                        <td className="text-danger text-right">{car.sale}%</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td className="text-primary text-right">
                          <strong>
                            Total:
                          </strong>
                        </td>
                        <td className="text-primary text-right">
                          <strong>
                            ${car.price-car.price*car.sale/100}
                          </strong>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td className="text-primary text-right">Est. Lease:</td>
                        <td className="text-primary text-right">$230/m*</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td className="text-primary text-right">Est. Finance:</td>
                        <td className="text-primary text-right">$330/m*</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td className="text-right"></td>
                        <td className="text-right">
                          <Link to={`/cars/${car.id}`}>
                          <Button className="btn btn-success">More</Button>
                        </Link>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  </Table>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
    </div>
          ))}

  );


};
}
```

export default Car;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an arrow function `car => ( ... )` without a function body `{}`, so you don't need the `return` statement since the JSX will be returned implicitly.

Also make sure that you return `carList` from the `render` method, or there will be nothing to render for this component.

```
class CarsList extends Component {
  // ...

  render() {
    const { Cars, CarsLoading } = this.state;
    const orderedcars = Cars;

    let carList;
    if (CarsLoading) {
      carList = <div className="TaskList-empty">Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      carList = (
        <ul className="TaskList">
          {Cars.map(car => (
            <div>
              <Row>
                <Col md="12">
                  <div className="card border-secondary mb-3">
                    <div className="card-header text-success">
                      <h4>
                        <Link to={`/cars/${car.id}`}>
                          {car.year} {car.make} {car.model} {car.trim}
                        </Link>
                      </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-body">
                      <Row>
                        <Col md="5">
                          <CardImg
                            className="carlist-margin"
                            top
                            width="100%"
                            src={car.link}
                            alt={car.make}
                          />
                        </Col>
                        <Col md="4">
                          <Table className="striped">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td>Engine:</td>
                                <td>{car.engine}</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>Drive Type:</td>
                                <td>{car.drive_type}</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>Body:</td>
                                <td>{car.body_type}</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>Exterior Color:</td>
                                <td>{car.ext_color}</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>Interior Color:</td>
                                <td>{car.int_color}</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>Transmission:</td>
                                <td>{car.transmission}</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>VIN:</td>
                                <td>{car.vin}</td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </Table>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md="3">
                          <Table className="striped">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td className="text-primary text-right">
                                  <strong>MSRP:</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td className="text-primary text-right">
                                  <strong>${car.price}</strong>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td className="text-danger text-right">
                                  Dealer Discount:
                                </td>
                                <td className="text-danger text-right">
                                  {car.sale}%
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td className="text-primary text-right">
                                  <strong>Total:</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td className="text-primary text-right">
                                  <strong>
                                    ${car.price - (car.price * car.sale) / 100}
                                  </strong>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td className="text-primary text-right">
                                  Est. Lease:
                                </td>
                                <td className="text-primary text-right">
                                  $230/m*
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td className="text-primary text-right">
                                  Est. Finance:
                                </td>
                                <td className="text-primary text-right">
                                  $330/m*
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td className="text-right" />
                                <td className="text-right">
                                  <Link to={`/cars/${car.id}`}>
                                    <Button className="btn btn-success">
                                      More
                                    </Button>
                                  </Link>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </Table>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </div>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    }

    return carList;
  }
}
```

Comment: now its giving me an error saying Nothing was returned from render and that im missing a return statement . Any idea what this means?

Comment: @LeonBogod Try to copy the code from the answer above and see if that works. You had forgotten to return `carList` from the end of the `render` method.

Comment: yes ive copied the code and its giving me that error

Comment: @LeonBogod I removed the `if` from `else if`. It might be that the cars array can be empty.

Comment: oh wow thank you so much ! so the reason it was giving me that error was because the array was empty?

Comment: @LeonBogod The array was most likely empty after the loading was complete, the `else if` condition was `false`, and nothing was returned from render.